# sed replace (incorrectly) stopped at the first match

Tags: sed

`echo '/foo/bar/test/' | sed -e "s/\//|/"`

Expected : `|foo|bar|test|`
Actual : `|foo/bar/test/`

What is wrong?

Comment: `echo '/foo/bar/test/' | sed -e "s/\//|/g"` may be

Comment: try `echo '/foo/bar/test/' | sed -e "s/\//|/g"`

Comment: what about sed 's///g\/sounds/\/apps\/soundboard\/sounds/' soundboard.json > new_soundboard.json ? as i got error unkown option to s

Answer (score 0):

As the comments by Jose Ricardo Bustos M. and Patrick Trentin indicate, `sed` is working correctly. The `s///` command replaces **only the first** match, unless the behaviour is changed with a flag. To replace **all** matches, use `s///g`. To replace the `n`th match, e.g. the third match, instead of the first, use `s///3`.